# How to read zip file through getResourceAsStream with relative path?

Tags: java, maven, zip, inputstream

I used to use this method to read text files in my maven's resources/ directory, so that I can use relative path:

```
public static BufferedReader fileReaderAsResource(String filePath) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
        if (is == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(" Not found: " + filePath);
        }
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, DEFAULT_ENCODING));
    }
```

Now I need to read zip file due to its size and I still want to use relative path to file in my "resources" directory. Is there a way to do this?

I have this method to read zip file, but it only reads in file through absolute path:

```
public static BufferedReader fileZipReader(String fileName) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        URL zipUrl = IOUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
        File zipFile = new File(zipUrl.toURI());
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);
        for (Enumeration e = zip.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
            if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zip.getInputStream(zipEntry)));
            }
        }
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found: " + fileName);
    }
```

How to read zip file through relative path to my standard maven's resources/ directory?

Comment: `File zipFile = new File(zipUrl.toURI());` A `File` cannot represent an URL pointing to a Zip entry. If code truly needs a file, it will be necessary to extract the information to a file, first.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap an InputStream with a ZipInputStream, i.e. :

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
if (is == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException(" Not found: " + filePath);
}
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
```

EDIT:

Use the method above named as "fileReaderZipAsResource", I read the file normally:

```
try {
            BufferedReader br = fileReaderZipAsResource(qaFilePath);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid entry ... 2");
                }
                line = line.trim();
                textKGKB.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But the debugging shows that the program doesn't enter the loop. It simply pass by the loop and continue the logic, without throwing an exception either. My text file is a 4-column text file delimited with tab key. I simply zip it and name it as xyy.zip, and pass it as parameter to the method above.

What's the problem? Does the wrapping of ZipInputStream really work?

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work. What I did is to simply zip the text file and use this method. Please see my edit.

Comment: Can you post your file?